# JPA / JPQL - bulk update

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have to perform a bulk update on a table.
Making a fast example :

```
 UPDATE Book b SET b.amount = b.amount + 1 WHERE b IN ( :books )
```

The problem is that b.amount can be or a NULL value or an int, and if there is a NULL value it should behave as b.amount would be equal to 1.

Is there any "cast" in JPA/JPQL or any other way to work-around this problem,

Thank you in advance,

Regards,
P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE Book b SET b.amount = COALESCE(b.amount, 1) + 1 WHERE b IN ( :books )
```

Comment: Is this JPA specific or Hibernate specific, since I do not want to be provider dependent ?

Comment: @redbull: It was introduced in JPA 2.0, before JPA 2.0 it was Hibernate-specific.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed, up!

Answer (score 1):

I would go and fix the nulls first with a separate query:

```
UPDATE Book set b.amount = 0 WHERE b.amount IS NULL
```

And also make it impossible to insert `null`, if it is not a legal value for your logic. For example have it `@Column(nullable=false)`

Comment: In longer term this seems to be a better approach ( which I will use later ), but for now I do not have this flexibility

Answer (score 0):

I used the following way to get the JDBC connection from the current JPA provider.

```
SessionImplementor si = (SessionImplementor) em.unwrap(Session.class);
Connection connection = si.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("...");
// Do something
pstmt.addBatch();
pstmt.executeBatch();
si.getJdbcConnectionAccess().releaseConnection(connection);
```