# Hibernate: Deadlock found when trying to obtain lock

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate in my project and I am getting random Apparent Deadlocks for very simple database operations.

There is one of the Stack Traces: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/8999006 – What confuses me, that the first Exception is RollbackException and then there are LockAquisition Exceptions.

The problem happens often on similar clauses:

```
@Transactional
public void setLastActivity() {
    User user = em.findById(...);
    user.setLastActivity(new Date());
    em.merge(user);
    em.flush();
}
```

I am quite stuck as I don't know whether it is problem of Hibernate, MySQL or C3P0.

My Hibernate configuration:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${database.structure}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${database.connection}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${database.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${database.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${database.driver}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.writedelay">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation">disabled</prop>
            <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool provider -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statementsPerConnection">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">120</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">8</prop>
```

EDIT1:

- I wrote above there were Apparent Deadlocks happening - that was wrong, only "Deadlock found when trying to obtain lock" happen.

EDIT2:

This happens also on these methods - those NEEDS to be annotated with @Transactional:

```
@Transactional
public void setLastActivity() {
    em.insertNative("table")
           .values(...)
           .execute();
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as the actual exceptions you are getting with stacktrace. Here I mean, not on some external site which might be blocked by corporate firewalls.

Comment: You probably want to set autocommit=false.

Comment: Gimby: The stacktrace is given - look more carefuly. brettw: Can you give more information why should it help?

Comment: you use the phrase "Apparent Deadlock", but that does not appear in your gist. are you seeing APPARENT DEADLOCK messages from c3p0 at some point? if so, can you reproduce that with the long status message that follows?

Comment: Can you show more of your code. How you open and close a session/transaction.

Comment: Steve: Please see my edits. Zeus: See the edited code - it happens in such simple methods.

Comment: What happens when you get rid of the @Transactional?
Had deadlocks with hibernate recently due to @Transactional annotations.

Comment: some business transactions in the application could be holding locks for a long time, increasing the odds of deadlock. Is Transactional being used with non default isolation somewhere? Also could you post the code code FollowRemote.getFollowsFor, and which is line 186 in that method mentioned in the stacktrace

Comment: there is something strange in the setLastActivity method, user is an attached entity, so there is no need to merge it as merging has no effect on attached entities. Also flush just before the end of the method is not needed, as spring will do the flush for us. Is there any special reason why the manual flush is made? it could be related

Comment: Jan Vladimir Moster: Well when I removed it, I was getting "No transaction is in progress." exceptions – I thought that when accessing entity manager, there must always me transaction?

Comment: jhadesdev: In the method, there is just simple select statement, and the method is not @Transactional.

Comment: It seems, that if I call native SQL update, the method needs to be annotated with @Transactional, otherwise I am getting: `Executing an update/delete query` Exceptions.

Comment: @Vojtěch what is your transaction isolation level , is this multithread environment ? have you looked into database , is there any lock at that moment ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the deadlocks happen so frequently, it looks like some of the threads of the application are holding locks for an extended period of time.

Each thread in the application will use it's own database connection/connections while accessing the database, so from the point of view of the database two threads are two distinct clients that compete for database locks.

If a thread holds locks for an extended period of time and acquires them in a certain order, and a second thread comes along acquiring the same locks but on a different order, deadlock is bound to occur (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951275/would-you-explain-lock-ordering) for details on this frequent deadlock cause).

Also deadlocks are occurring in read operations, which means that some threads are acquiring read locks as well. This happens if the threads are running transactions in `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation level or `SERIALIZABLE`.

To solve this, try searching for usages of `Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ` and `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE`in the project, to see if this is being used.

As an alternative, use the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level and annotate the entities with `@Version`, to handle concurrency using [optimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html#d0e2225) instead.

Also try to identify long running transactions, this happens sometimes when the `@Transactional` is placed at the wrong place and wraps for example the processing of a whole file in the example of a batch processing, instead of doing transactions line by line.

This a log4j configuration to log the creation/deletion of entity managers and transactions begin/commit/rollback:

```
   <!-- spring entity manager and transactions -->
<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" additivity ="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger >
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction" additivity ="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger >
```

1. **Can I somehow execute update query (either JPA/Native) without having to lock the table via @Transactional?**

Update queries are possible via native queries or [JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178473/jpa-jpql-bulk-update).

2. **Can I somehow get into session without using @Transactional?** *For instance, scheduled thread tries to read Lazy field on Entity yields to LazyInitializationException - no session, if the method is not annotated with @Transactional*

In methods without `@Transactional`, queries will be executed in it's own entity manager and return only detached entities, as thee session is closed immediatelly after the query is run.

so the lazy initialization exceptions in methods without `@Transactional` is normal. You can set them to `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not found any Isolation setting: the default is always used. The most interesting for me would be to find which transactions are those who cause the locks. From the exceptions I see only those, who can't acquire them. Is there a way to find them?

Comment: I just added some log4j configuration to log the transaction begin/commit/rollback, it will log the isolation and propagation as well. there is logging for creation/destruction of entity managers as well.

Comment: Did the DBAs have a look at the DB, to see if something else is running on it, the cause for the deadlocks? They should be able to provide a lot of input

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm the DBA, so :-) Well, I will accept your answer, because I am on the right track now. I have a few minor questions for you: 1. Can I somehow execute update query (either JPA/Native) without having to lock the table via @Transactional? 2. Can I somehow get into session without using @Transactional? For instance, scheduled thread tries to read Lazy field on Entity yields to LazyInitializationException - no session, if the method is not annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: I have added these two questions in the answer, bulk updates are possible and LazyInitializationException in methods without @Transactional is normal

Comment: Ad "Update queries are possible via native queries or JPQL.": I do them, but they _require_ @Transactional, otherwise I get Transaction required exception. Ad 2) Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is the error with MySQL.

The most easy way to resolve & avoid deadlocks is to reorder the DB operations happening in the application.

Deadlock mostly occurs when more than one resource/connection try to acquire more than one lock at opposite orders, as below:

```
connection 1: locks key(1), locks key(2);
connection 2: locks key(2), locks key(1);
```

In the scenario when both the connections execute at the same time, connection 1 will acquire lock on key(1), and connection 2 on key(2). After that both the connections will wait for other to release the lock on the key. This results in deadlock.

But, a little tweak in the order of the transactions, then deadlocks can be avoided.

```
connection 1: locks key(1), locks key(2);
connection 2: locks key(1), locks key(2);
```

Above re-order is deadlock proof.

Other ways to avoid deadlocks is to have a transaction management mechanism. [Transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) by Spring is almost plug-n-play. Moreover, you can have a deadlock retry policy in place. An interesting deadlock retry via Spring AOP can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/automatic-deadlock-retry). This way you just need to add the annotation to the method you want to retry in case of deadlock.

For more debug logs on deadlock to find out which statements are suspicious, try running the "show engine innodb status" diagnostics. Also, you can have a look at **[How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)**.

**UPDATE:** A scenario for deadlocks in transactional DB operations.

In a transactional database, a deadlock happens when two processes each within its own transaction updates two rows of information but in the opposite order. For example, process A updates row 1 then row 2 in the exact time-frame process B updates row 2 then row 1. Process A can't finish updating row 2 until process B is finished, but it cannot finish updating row 1 until process A finishes. No matter how much time is allowed to pass, this situation will never resolve itself and because of this database management systems will typically kill the transaction of the process that has done the least amount of work.

Shishir

Comment: I understand the problem and I have already read similar descriptions. But this happens with very simple transactions as I mentioned above. I am not locking the tables manually, it is done by Hibernate and the @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Just curious, does the application work without deadlock situation if you remove the @Transactional annotation? 95% of the deadlock situation in Hibernate arise from unordered DB transactions, and can be avoided if the DDLs & DMLs are re-ordered to a more synchronized order.

Comment: I thought that all entitymanager calls must be wrapped within a transaction – that is why it is annotated. So it is not necessary?

Comment: Transaction is necessary but there can be multiple transactions operating at a given point of time in application which might end in deadlocks if operations not handled in a proper order. I have added another explanation for deadlocks in transaction DB in my answer.